# django-admin.py not running

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, path

I'll add another django-admin.py question, as none of the other questions seem to cover my issue:

I've installed django via pip:

```
$ pip install django
```

My pip and Python versions are:

```
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Specifically, python is version 2.7.14. At this point I expected to run

```
$ django-admin startproject myTestProject
```

which would then create my project folders in the current directory.

However, this returns

```
Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django
```

This confuses me, since when I ran

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Further, I checked where the file django-admin.py is located:

```
$ find -iname "django-admin.py"
./.local/bin/django-admin.py
./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
```

So it seems like django-admin.py is in my PATH. **Why then can I not run it?**

(extra info: I do have python 3.6.3 installed, too. But I don't think this version has anything to do with pip or django.)

Comment: Can you try installing with `pip2 install django` instead? Once I've seen a system having Python 2 default by pip pointing to pip3

Comment: i suggest you use a virtualenv. then you will never face this problem

Comment: do `import django` and check `django.__version__`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you always use a virtual environment manager with your Django projects, such as virtualenvwrapper ( `pip install virtualenvwrapper`  or `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper` see [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#python-versions) for installation instructions)

then you can `mkvirtualenv myprojectname` and install django into the virtual environment (`pip install django`). then you will not face any problems such as this

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a few things,

1. You should be looking for `django-admin` not `django-admin.py`.
2. Your paths have `/usr/local/bin`, what you're looking at is `/home/<your user>/.local` which is certainly not the right place.
3. As everybody suggested, use `virtualenv` for maintaining your projects and its dependencies cleanly and nicely.